# alternative to webapp2.WSGIApplication after migrating to google cloud ndb

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I migrated from `google.appengine.ext.webapp` and ran into an issue with `webapp2.WSGIApplication`. I am using Django as the backend

the main part looks like this

```
application =webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                       ('/warmup', warmupHandler)
                                       ('/api/layer', LayerService),
                                        debug=False)

def main():
     google.appengine.ext.webapp.util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

I have tried using this code snippet provided by google cloud as a replacement and it did no help.

def wsgi_middleware(app):
client = ndb.Client()

```
 def middleware(request):
     with client.context()
          return app(request)

 return middleware
```

They also have code snippits but i think this is for Flask, and i use django

```
def ndb_wsgi_middleware(wsgi_app):
    def middleware(environ, start_response):
        with client.context():
            return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    return middleware
```

In the current setup I have, all I get is a 404 error. Meaning its not picking up the templates

Comment: What problem are you running into? Are there any error messages?

Comment: the problem is that i get a 404 error because the application is not routing correctly.  I think it is because i am no longer using webapp2 and I am looking for a replacement

Comment: To understand better, where the error is coming from, can you please describe your set up? Can you provide the Google documentation you found about this?

Comment: I have found some documentation here: (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/migrating-to-cloud-ndb#multithreaded_apps). Would this be appropriate for you so that we can build on it?